# debian系のOSでルーティングが変更される事象

Tags: linux

Debian系のOSでルーティングが突如変更される事象が稀に発生します。
そのため、ネットワークデバイスは立ち上がっているのですが、通信ができない状態です。

考えられる原因について、ご助言をお願い申し上げます。

Comment: もう少し詳しい情報が欲しいところです。ネットワークは固定IP or DHCP、変更されてしまうのはOSを使用中でも突然 or 再起動したタイミングだけ等。/var/log/ 以下のログファイルなども調べてみると何か手がかりがあるかもしれません。

Comment: ルーティングが正常な時の下記の情報を集めておいて、突如変更されたときと比較することで、問題を絞り込めるのではないでしょうか。``cat /etc/resolv.conf``、``traceroute <対象のfqdn>``、``ifconfig -a``、``dig <対象のfqdn>

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。　ネットワークは固定で、変更のタイミングは突如。syslogを始め、各ログには特に変更されたと思われるログはありませんでした。resolvには127.0.0.1を設定しています。

Comment: ディストリビューションとバージョン、どのようにRouteを設定しているか、どのように変更されたかといったことが質問からは判断つきませんので、具体的な回答はつきにくいと感じました。もしよければ、もう少し具体的に書いてもらえると回答が付きやすくなると思います。